# How to change the search query from AND to OR in Opencart?

Tags: opencart

**Opencart**: v.1.5.6.4

When someone searches for "*iphone nikon*" in Opencart's search input text field the results are:
"*There is no product that matches the search criteria.*" (example - https://o-v156x.my-soul.net/index.php?route=product/search&search=iphone%20nikon)

What I want to achieve is to change the search query from **AND** to **OR** to get results:

- iphone
- Nikon D300

or all the products where these words appear in **product's name**.

I am not interested in live search (auto-complete or auto-suggest or auto-correct).

I am pretty sure that the changes I want to make (by using vQmod) are inside the file `/catalog/model/catalog/product.php`.
Where exactly is the code needed to be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

**catalog/model/catalog/product.php**

1. Locate the function `getProducts()`
2. Find the following code block in relevant function:

`foreach ($words as $word) {
    $implode[] = "pd.name LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape($word) . "%'";
}`

`if ($implode) {
    $sql .= " " . implode(" AND ", $implode) . "";
}`

and replace the code block with:

`foreach ($words as $word) {
    $implode[] = "pd.name LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape($word) . "%'";
}`

`if ($implode) {
    $sql .= " " . implode(" OR ", $implode) . "";
}`

3. Find the following code inside the `getTotalProducts()` function

   `foreach ($words as $word) {
       $implode[] = "pd.name LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape($word) . "%'";
   }`

`if ($implode) {
    $sql .= " " . implode(" AND ", $implode) . "";
}`

and replace with following

`foreach ($words as $word) {
    $implode[] = "pd.name LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape($word) . "%'";
}`

`if ($implode) {
    $sql .= " " . implode(" OR ", $implode) . "";
}`
Hope it helps, CHEERS!

Comment: Don't forget to add the same change in getTotalProducts() function also in same file, otherwise you will get the incorrect search products count in pagination.

Comment: Thanks **Zaman** & **Ketan**. Check out the results https://o-v156x.my-soul.net/index.php?route=product/search&search=apple%20samsung%20macbook :)

Answer (score 0):

Look for the function called `getProducts()` in the file `/catalog/model/catalog/product.php`. Within this look for something similar to the following line which deals with the variable `filter_name`

```
if ($implode) {
  $sql .= " " . implode(" AND ", $implode) . "";
}
```

You will have to change the `AND` to `OR` in the above statement, but remember if you make this change in the core any updates to OpenCart will change this back to what the update is.